# npm CI && npm run build is failing in github actions, I'm using firebase to deploy the project

Tags: firebase, github, npm, github-actions, vite

npm CI && npm run build is failing in github actions I'll paste the yaml file below.

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
"on": pull_request
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: "${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.SECRET }}"
          projectId: projectId
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXNiG.png)

I tried to remove npm CI, deleted node_modules package and package.json file in local and re-installed everything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have package-lock.json in the root directory.
You can add it using: `npm i --package-lock-only`

And try to set the ci to empty, eg:

```
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
        env:
          CI: ""
```

Comment: I already have package-lock.json file inside project folder. I tried to delete that and create a new one. but that didn't work too.

Comment: Maybe try this code, it is what worked for me:
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
        env:
          CI: ""

- You could also try with npm ci instead of npm install